# Как лучше реализовать БД в программе учета клиентов?

Tags: c++, база-данных, qt

Я начинающий кодер, но подрабатываю в ИП. Так вот, суть в следующем, я взялся написать программу учета клиентов, то есть программа с граф.интерфейсом, где будет реализован поиск, редактирование, добавление и удаление клиентов, их полей, номеров, адресов и т.д. язык выбран c++, для графики Qt, в этом проблем не будет, я все основное "Тело" напишу без проблем, проблема и вопрос встал в хранении этих данных. Я понимаю, что надо использовать БД, но посоветуйте, как лучше поступить. Юзать облачные бд,  или же поставить бд к ним на сервер, или какие еще варианты есть? Какую бд для этого посоветуете, учитывая, что это ИП и клиентов будет максимум тысяча-пару, то есть объем данных небольшой. Чтобы без костылей с qt и c++ можно было написать, может и не супер продуктивно, но работающее приложение?

P.s. я в БД полный ноль, никогда ими не занимался, может вовсе не понимаю сути, будьте пожалуйста снисходительны)

Comment: Попробовать SQLite? С таким объемом справится на ура...

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html

Comment: это все уже реализовано до вас